# How do you enable MountFlag in docker config in EKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, s3fs

I am trying to work with [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) and other fuse implementation to mount s3 buckets eg. [csi-s3](https://github.com/ctrox/csi-s3) and both have requirement that

`Docker daemon must allow shared mounts (systemd flag MountFlags=shared)`

However, I am not user how to do that in EKS or even using terraform. Could not find any documentation on how to enable MountFlags=shared in Kubernetes without logging into nodes and maually runnning some commands.